# jQuery - Set html of an element on select change

Tags: jquery, select, text

I have a select element called JobsList and I need it to set the html value of another element, jobDesc. I don't understand what I'd need to do, or where to start, I'm relatively new to jQuery.

It would have to set the text of the element to something predefined for each option, like if the option selected was Citizen, it would set jobDesc to "You have no real role in society".

Comment: show your html code or setup a fiddle in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Show some code. Please edit your question and add nicely formatted html and what script you already have

Comment: I have the HTML, but no jQuery, I don't know where to start on that.

Comment: @user2142702 paste the HTML Code in your question or go to JSfiddle.net site and there you paste the html and sav, then share the link

Answer (score 1):

```
var job_list_value = $('#JobsList').val();
var message;

if (job_list_value === "Citizen") {
    message = "You have no real role in society");
} else if (job_list_value === "other") {
    message = "other statement";
} else {
    message = 'Default';
}

$('#elementId').html(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('#JobsList').val() == "Citizen")
   $('#elementId').html("You have no real role in society");
else    if($('#JobsList').val() == "other")
   $('#elementId').html("other statement");
```

if select options are more then use switch instead of if-else.

Import jQuery files before using this code.

Answer (score 0):

use change event to track the chnaged event... and put the value...

try this

```
 $('#joblistID').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Citizen"){
        $('#elementId').val("You have no real role in society");//if input
        $('#elementId').text("You have no real role in society");// or if otner element
    }
 });
```

you can work for others in similar ways..

or make an array of options value

**html**

```
...
<option value="citizen">Citizen</option>
<option value="test">Test</option>
....
```

**jquery**

```
 var a= new Array();
a['citizen']='You have no real role in society';
a['test']='test word'
.....
$('#joblistID').change(function(){
        var currvalue=$(this).val();
        $('#elementId').val(a[currvalue]);//if input
        $('#elementId').text([currvalue]);// or if otner element

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

**Javascript**

```
// # is used for filtering by element ID
    if($('#JobsList').val() == "Citizen")
       $('#jobDesc').html("You have no real role in society");
    else    if($('#JobsList').val() == "other")
       $('#jobDesc').html("other statement");
```

Answer (score 0):

See if your html is like this:

### html:

```
<select id='joblist'>
  <option value='0'>---job list---</option>
  <option value='Student'>Student</option>
  <option value='Citizen'>Citizen</option>
</select>
<div id='jobdesc'></div>
```

### then jQuery should be:

```
$(function(){
     $('#joblist').change(function () {
         if ($(this).val() == 'Student') {
             $('#jobdesc').html('You need to study good things.');
         } else if ($(this).val() == 'Citizen') {
             $('#jobdesc').html('"You have no real role in society" it\'s not true.');
         } else {
             $('#jobdesc').html('Please choose a job from above list.');
         }
     }).change();
});
```

[**CHECKOUT THIS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/REVYC/)